# Not getting changes after sometime from gmail watch

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am using gmail APIs to sync emails with my portal. I have added around 10 gmail accounts and have added watch for all of them which is working via gmail pub-sub. I am getting changes perfectly for around 8 accounts where as for 1 or two accounts, i am not getting changes via pub-sub topic to my web-hook server.

by manual (API)call to fetch changes, i am getting further changes as well But not via pub-sub topic.

The code I am using to create watch is:

```
let oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret);
oauth2Client.credentials = { 'access_token': accessToken, 'refresh_token': refreshToken }; 
gmail.users.watch({ 
    auth: oauth2Client, 
    userId: 'me', 
    resource: { topicName: googleAppsSMTP.topicName } 
  }, (err, response) => { 
    console.log(response); 
    defer.resolve(response); 
});
```

Is there anything I am missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#limitations) regarding notifications? The maximum notification rate of a Gmail user is 1 event per second. Notifications above that rate are dropped. Is it always the same accounts that you are not getting changes from?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yes i am aware of the limitation but the question is notification will dropped if i will receive more than one notification per second but i will always be able receive that one notification. in my case i am not getting a single notification for those accounts.

Comment: So it is always the same accounts that you are not getting notifications from?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yes

Comment: Hard to know what's going on with the provided info. Are you sure you have access to those accounts?

Comment: @Iamblichus Yes, the thing is that in that account  i am continuously receiving the emails like every 3-4 min i am receiving a new email where as in other accounts it's like i am receiving a new email nearly 30-40 mins.